# How to compare two strings in GitHub Actions

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to compare two strings and run some commands according to the results.

Here is my script:

```yaml
- name: Get Version of Release Branch
  run: echo "branch_version=$(echo $branch_name | sed 's/release\///g')" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      
- name: Get Version of Project
  run: echo "build_version=$(cat notification-abstractions.csproj | grep PackageVersion | sed -e 's/PackageVersion//g' -e 's/<//g' -e 's/>//g' -e 's/\///g' -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//')" >> $GITHUB_ENV


- name: Versions
  run: | 
    echo build version=$build_version
    echo branch version=$branch_version

- name: Fail PR if versions not matching
  if: ${{ '${{ env.branch_version }}' != '${{ env.build_version }}' }}
  run: exit 1
```

[image]

build and branch version is the same but somehow expression returns `true`.

I have tried:

- `if: env.branch_version != env.build_version`
- `if: ${{ env.branch_version != env.build_version }}`
- `if: (( ${{ env.branch_version }} != ${{ env.build_version }} ))`

but none of them works properly.

Comment: How are the `build_version` and `branch_version` variables defined in your config? Please add that to the question as well. I just tested and it's working fine with `${{ env.BRANCH_VERSION != env.BUILD_VERSION }}`. See https://github.com/iamazeem/test/actions/runs/3929787604/jobs/6719013611.

Comment: Hello I have edited my questions. I am parsing branch version from name of the branch. and build version I read that from csproj file.

Comment: Hi! Could you please print those extracted versions in brackets `[]` to make sure there is no preceding or following whitespace, and newlines?

Comment: Wow there is a new line at build_version thanks dude. I was struggling with this over  3 hours :D

Comment: Good catch! You can use the `tr` command to get rid of that e.g. `tr -d '\n'`.

Comment: Also, if `echo` is adding that, you can use `echo -n` to skip that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version strings should be comparable with the `!=` operator.

I have tested this:

```
if: ${{ env.build_version != env.branch_version }}
```

and, it works fine.

Please make sure that the version strings don't have any preceding or following spaces, or newlines.

- Use `tr -d '\n'` to remove newline characters if there are any.
- `echo` also adds a trailing newline. Use `echo -n` to suppress that.
- And, `grep` can directly take a file as an argument, you don't have to `cat` and then `grep`.